# Interface Builder picking up wrong header file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, interface-builder, xib

I have two header files with EXACT same name in my project, it seems interface builder is picking the wrong one for "File Owner" dropdown, how can i change it to use the other header file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should change the name of one of the header files!

Although you can certainly have same-named files in different folders within a project-- and in some cases, such as when you pull in third-party libraries, it'll just happen-- headers that you reference from Interface Builder should be a small subset that are under your control as your UI pieces. You should just rename one of the classes.

(There may be a way to get IB to differentiate, but even if there is, it seems like a fragile setup.)